# Redirect from one domain to another with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I run a bilingual website which is accessible via two domains (beispiel.com and example.com.

Now I want to set up the following redirects:

- All urls beginning with beispiel.com/fr should be redirected to example.com/fr*
- All urls beginning with exemple.com/de should be redirected to beispiel.com/de*

Of course, this should apply to all links, as from example.com/de/title1 should lead to beispiel.com/de/title1

I have to implement the whole thing in .htaccess ...

I tried

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^beispiel\.com/fr$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/fr/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: The value you are trying to compare `%{HTTP_HOST}` to, is not a host name.

Answer (score 0):

This probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^beispiel\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^fr/ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^de/ https://beispiel.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```